# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED Route 53 / Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have been trying to connect my domain with my elastic beanstalk instance.

My domain was purchased off GoDaddy and I have updated the nameservers to point to AWS and verified through dig. If dig comes up with the NS, it means GoDaddy is properly configured to point to the DNS right?
The Test Record Set function also does not show any error and has a proper response returned which has NOERROR

Problem is I still receive an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED everytime I try to load the website on browsers even tried on different devices

I have also checked the alias used in my Hosted Zone and its up and running

What I have already done:
 Initialized and created Beanstalk environment - Up and Running
 Public Hosted Zone - Created A record for www.mysite.com
 GoDaddy DNS NS - updated with AWS 4 nameservers

Checks I have done:
Internal Test Record for A www.mysite.com
Dig Command

[image: browsererror]
[image: digresponse]

What could I be missing?

UPDATE***

So I figured "www.mysite.com' was working but 'mysite.com' alone was not. I'm assuming route53 will automatically use the www A record? But seems like its not?

Hope ya'll could help

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work.

Looks like besides creating a www A record, I had to create a record for the root domain i.e mysite.com in the Record Set of my Hosted Zone

Solved!

Comment: Please, select your own answer as the selected answer.